# How to encode PHP string of HTML for use as string by JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I've got the following code:

```
<iframe id="uniqueId" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
<script>
    var iframeObject = document.getElementById("uniqueId");
    var iframeContent = iframeObject.contentWindow.document;
    iframeContent.open();
    iframeContent.write("<?php echo $htmlString ?>");
    iframeContent.close();
</script>;
```

I'm trying to insert user-generated HTML (metadata, `<html>`, `<head>`, `<body>`, `<script>`s and all), stored as a string in the PHP variable `$htmlString`, into the #uniqueId iframe for a browser/client to render.

I'm having a really hard time figuring out the proper way to safely escape/encode this string of HTML for use in the JavaScript I've written.

On the PHP side, I've tried `htmlspecialchars()`, `htmlentities()`, `json_encode()`, and some simple `str_replace()`s on `$htmlString`, but none of them does what I need them to. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: How about using both `htmlspecialchars()` and `str_replace()` like `str_replace(array("\r","\n"),"", htmlspecialchars($htmlString));`.

Comment: @imtheman, I would include the backslash (`"\\"`) in str_replace. Could get some funky results if the double quote after `$htmlString` is escaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feeling dumb; the issue was with the syntax of my JavaScript. Once I'd fixed those, `echo json_encode($htmlString)` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should save a code to a file and loads it by src attribute from another domain.

At least jsfiddle.net uses this way.

Comment: @jh1711 Yes, you right. I misunderstood the requirements when read the question. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Great. I'm not sure how if separate file helps in all cases, but at least  browsers won't assemble broken Javascript from different sources, and try to run whatever they collected.

Comment: @jh1711 If use a different domain as it jsfiddle does there is no way to access to the parent by the default same origin policy. So it must be safe.